Date String to Datetime object in a defined format
I'm getting the string "enddate" from my django backend api in the following format :
"enddate" : "2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30"


My purpose is to convert it to Datetime in my flutter app in the following forma:

dd/MM/yyyy  i.e 24/08/2024

so that it becomes easy to read for the users.
Based on the several stack posts i have read,I have figured the following function but I cant seem to figure to use DateFormat function in the correct manner for the input date. Here is what i have tried :
DateTime parseEndDate(String enddate) {
    var inputFormat = DateFormat('yy/MM/dd');
    var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(enddate.toString()); // <--yy/MM/dd format

    var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
    var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate); // <-- dd/MM/yy format

    return DateTime.parse(outputDate).toLocal();
  }

EDIT :
Based on sevral solutions below, here is what ive implemeneted:
Here is the code snippet of which the return statement is the issue.
DateTime parseEndDate(String enddate) {
    DateTime inputDate = DateTime.parse(enddate);
    var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'); // <-- dd/MM/yyformat

    var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
    return DateTime.parse(outputDate).toLocal();
   
  }

Turns out the return statement DateTime.parse() is giving me 'Invalid date format' "24/08/2024".

Rewrite the function such that it will parse the date string to DateTime and return the String of your desired format
String parseEndDate(String enddate) {
    var inputDate = DateTime.parse(enddate);
    var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
    return outputFormat.format(inputDate);
}


Hi. The purpose is to return a datetime. How best to do it ?

@Earthling formatted date will always be of type string.

@Earthling There is no formatted DateTime, if you want to display dates in a specific format then it will always be a string.

Your parseEndDate function has the following two issues:

The var inputFormat = DateFormat('yy/MM/dd'); is incorrect because the format of the enddate string is yyyy-MM-dd.
The outputFormat (dd/MM/yyyy) cannot be repeatedly parsed to a DateTime object.

You can write the following string extension functions to get either a formatted date string or a DateTime object:
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

extension DateParsing on String {
  String toDateString({String format = 'dd/MM/yyyy'}) {
    final inputDate = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat(format).format(inputDate);
  }
  
  DateTime toDateObject() {
    return DateTime.parse(this);
  }
}

Then use it like this:
'2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30'.toDateString(); //returns a formatted date string
'2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30'.toDateObject(); //returns a DateTime object
//or you can also parse to a different format
'2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30'.toDateString(format: 'dd-MM-yyyy');


DateTime.parse gives me invalid format.

Your returned datetime is in ISO 8601 format, so Flutter can easy to parse it to datetime object using DateTime.parse() method. This method automatically handles the ISO 8601 format, including the timezone offset.
String dateTimeString = "2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString);

Please note that the input datetime string needs to follow the ISO 8601 format, which uses hyphens (-) as separators for the date parts, not slashes (/). If you use slashes, it will result in an error.
There are two options:

Replace slashes with hyphens before using DateTime.parse().
Use another library, like intl, to parse the input.



String dateString = "2024/08/20";
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
DateTime parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);




DateTime.parse gives me invalid format.

@Earthling DateTime.parse() expects the date string to follow the ISO 8601 format, which uses hyphens (-) as separators for the date parts, not slashes (/). so you have 2 options:

replace slashes by hyphens before use DateTime.parse()
Use another library to parse, like intl


I just updated my answer. Please check

understood. Is DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd") the 'desired' format or is it the format of the dateString already existing?

@Earthling it's the original format of input dateString you want to parse. You need to know the input format first.

Try below code:
With Package - intl
 String withPackage(String enddate) {
    var inputDate = DateTime.parse(enddate);
    return DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(inputDate);
  }

print('With Package - ${withPackage('2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30')}');

With out Package
String withoutPackage(String date) {
    DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse(date);

    String day = parsedDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String month = parsedDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String year = parsedDate.year.toString();
    return "$day/$month/$year"; // merge your expected format like dd/MM/yyyy
    }

print('With out Package - ${withoutPackage('2024-08-24T05:30:00+05:30')}');

